# Ιs it possible to disallow replacement of existing children entities on an entity using CascadeType or another annotation?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, cascade

Hi I am trying to make an API that uses an entity like that:

```
@Entity 
@NoArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter
class ParentEntity {
   @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
   private ChildEntity child;
}
```

let's say I have a parent entity at `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/parent-entities/1`

What I want to do is be able to PUT (update) in the following ways:

I want to be able to create new children entities on the fly, so this needs to be allowed (I think I need `CascadeType.PERSIST` for that):

```
PUT parent-entities/1 
{ "child": { "name": "new child" }}
```

updating child through parent needs to be allowed (I think I need `CascadeType.MERGE` for that)

```
PUT parent-entities/1
{ "child": { "id": 1, "name": "update existing child name" }}
```

I need to also be able to remove an item and remove it from database (I think I need `CascadeType.REMOVE` for that and also `orphanRemoval=true`) :

```
PUT parent-entities/1
{ "child": null} should remove child with id=1 from database
```

What I need help with is to **not** allow this:

```
PUT parent-entities/1
{ "child": { "id": 2, "name": "other existing child" }}
```

The answer may have to do with `CascadeType.REFRESH` and `CascadeType.DETACH` or `CascadeType.MERGE`

From my tests I couldn't make it work somehow. I actually managed to destroy a lot of existing childEntities making their names equal to null. My best guess was `CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE`

> Motiviation for the above: Frontend app was sending data for a specific child entity but with wrong id - this had the result to mutate the wrong entity that was completely unrelated and on top of that it was attached to the wrong parent. I still need the CascadeType.MERGE though.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you need a field `name` as unique?

Comment: no @Andronicus this is not needed

Comment: Then what is it that you want? You want to prohibit exchanging entities one with another?

Comment: @Andronicus yes I added a motivation quote behind what I want to do (if it is at all possible with annotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with just annotations. The solution will end up being adding updatable fields to specific columns.

You can prevent updates by removing CascadeType.MERGE, but then you won't be able to update ChildEntity.name either... Given you want to prevent updatability on specific fields, try the following.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3126773862335903987L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    **@JoinColumn(updatable = false)**
    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private ChildEntity child;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2903838577072685774L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
    private ParentEntity parent;
}
```

```java
@PutMapping
private ResponseEntity<ParentEntity> update(
        @RequestBody final ParentEntity entity) {
    return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(this.repo.saveAndFlush(entity)));
}
```

To demonstrate, enable show-sql in your application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Create initial entity

```
PUT /parent-entity
{
    "child": {
        "name": "alpha"
    }
}

Hibernate: insert into ChildEntity (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ParentEntity (child_id, id) values (?, ?)


PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID    CHILD   NAME
1           2           2       alpha
```

Update the name

```
PUT /parent-entity
{
    "id": 1,
    "child": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "beta"
    }
}

Hibernate: update ChildEntity set name=? where id=?


PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID    CHILD   NAME
1           2           2       beta
```

Attempt to update the ID

```
PUT /parent-entity
{
    "id": 1,
    "child": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "gamma"
    }
}

{
    "timestamp": "2020-01-23T11:08:02.056+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"FKGD5S6Q2V5J8MX33JL99EYCY5R: PUBLIC.PARENTENTITY FOREIGN KEY(CHILD_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CHILDENTITY(ID) (2)\"; SQL statement:\ndelete from ChildEntity where id=? [23503-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/parent-entities"
}


PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID    CHILD   NAME
1           2           2       beta
```

Similarly, if you want to prevent a non-referential column from being updated, simply use @Column(updatable = false)

Comment: awesome seems exactly the type of solution I wanted with no extra code - I will have a look locally to confirm it and I will accept and give the bounty - thank you :)